# Make Firefox read profiles.ini from other location pre-startup

Tags: firefox-addon, portable-applications

I'm making a Bootstrap addon.

On Firefox pre-startup I need to make it read a profiles.ini file from a custom path. Normally, it always tries to read profiles.ini at this location: `OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.userApplicationDataDir, 'profiles.ini');`

On Windows XP it is:`"C:\Documents and Settings\Noitidart\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox"`

Is it possible to make it read from another location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where `profiles.ini` is read from isn't exactly something you can influence. Given that no profile is selected at this point, your add-on obviously isn't active yet. Also, any preferences your add-on could write aren't active either because these would be stored in the profile as well. And if you look at the [actual implementation](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/4c4dcf7533cb/toolkit/profile/nsToolkitProfileService.cpp#l386) - there is indeed no configurability here, the `profiles.ini` file is always looked up in `userApplicationDataDir`. On Linux you could manipulate that value by setting the `HOME` environment variable differently, this approach won't work on Windows or OS X however - OS functions are used to locate the home directory there.

So what you *could* do is bypassing `profiles.ini` completely by passing in [`-profile c:\foo\bar` command line option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#-profile_.22.2Fpath.2Fto.2Fprofile.22) when you run Firefox, this will make Firefox use the specified profile directory. Other than that there isn't much you can do.

Comment: Holy moly I totally forgot you can pass the path to the profile! Let me test this out and get back to you! I don't C++ code so well so I couldn't figure out it would bypass. Thanks for that first half explanation as well, it confirms something for me, I didn't user userAppDatadir is where it always looked for profiles.ini I thought I just got lucky that it worked! Super thanks man!

Comment: Tested it and it was very important to change from -P to -profiles thanks @WladimirPalant!! :) This got my addon working on portable firefox now :)

Comment: FYI I just had to use this and forgot the exact thing. So posting here for others and my reference. You set the path to `'"' + FileUtils.getFile('XREExeF', []).path + '" -profile "' + OS.Constants.Path.profileDir + '" -no-remote'` which translates to: `"C:\Noitidart\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -profile "C:\Noitidart\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\my profile folder" -no-remote`